# occur "Could not resolve placeholder KName" exception when start a webApp

Tags: java, spring, placeholder

here is a blog of Spring:
http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

it introduce a new feature: user placeholder in import tag. 
example: `<import resource="com/bank/service/${customer}-config.xml"/>`

well, I'm 3.1 too.

and then, when i start MYAPP, the miracle did not happen..

here is my code:
(config.properties in sourceFolder):

```
kName = P0765
```

(spring's xml):

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">;
    <property name="location" value="classpath:config.properties" >;
</bean>

<import resource="readyData/${KName}.xml"/>
```

:(
What work did not do？？

Comment: Properties are case sensitive.
"K" char in ${KName}.xml is uppercase and in config.properties "k" char is in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Properties that are resolved in the import element have to be set as a JVM system property or system environment variable. It is described in the blog post you linked here.
This is because merging Spring configuration files happens before initializing beans (PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is a bean) at it probably won't change, see this rejected feature request https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1358